# .htaccess RewriteRule also rewriting my css, js and images files. how to ignore these?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want that when user input http://example.com/abc/123/jon/ in URL is actually show this file http://example.com/abc.php?id=123&name=jon and this is easily can be done by adding these lines into htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)/(.*)/ abc.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

but my abc.php file having some (css, js) files:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

and images like : img/logo.png

but because of my .htaccess file it is searching for style.css here : http://example.com/abc/123/jon/css/style.css
instead of http://example.com/css/style.css and similarly for js and images.

i already tried many similar answers here but none of them working for me.i am looking for .htaccess solutions for this.

Comment: add a / before css and js to tell the browser to look for those files starting from the root

Comment: yes it is working but i want a .htaccess solution not this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3701958/3492835. @Pinoniq is right.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use that:

```
RewriteEngine on
# not rewrite css, js and images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^abc/(.+)/(.+)/ abc.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]

# rewrite css, js and images, from root
RewriteRule ^abc/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.+)$ $1  [L]
```

If your final css (or js) directory is not at root, you can add the path before the last `$1`. Now it's: `/css/style.css` with `/abc/xxx/yyy`**/css/style.css**

Comment: Normally you should not need to do this if `css/` is in the same folder as `abc/`. But the important thing is that it works. I advise you to use however html: `<base href="">` when it's possible. But I see you have removed your message ...

Comment: I change my final `(.+)`, if you have problem with root.

Answer (score 7):

Just add before the `RewriteRule` one line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This means that if your request uri points at existing file, then next `RewriteRule` will not trigger.

If you want other way then this one should do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(css|js|png|jpg)$
```

You can add more extensions separated by pole (`|`)

Comment: You can't do that, because these are not real files in virtual directories.

Comment: This works fine. However, if this is not working then you may find that on many web servers when it comes to filenames, they are case sensitive. For example if your code is referencing a file as "sitenavigation.php" and the file is called "siteNavigation.php" then the rewrite would treat the file as missing and would therefore rewrite it.

Answer (score -1):

Answer by @Croises is correct but i have to add my full domain_url before $1

**so final Ans is:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)/(.*)/ abc.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^abc/[^/]+/[^/]+(/.+)$ http://example.com/$1  [L]
```

Comment: it is just for update, summary and final answer i already accepted your answer and gives credits to you also.

Comment: You have an error with 2 x `/` after `example.com//` the first from left regex....